# The insert statement conflicted with the foreign key constraint - SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server, entity-framework

I have 3 tables : Application, Control and Application Control which is basically a many to many relationship between Application and Control.

App table

```
App_ID int (PK)
.....
```

ApplicationControl table

```
FK_APP_ID int (PK)
FK_Controls_ID (PK)
```

and Control table

```
ID int (PK)
Name varchar(50)
```

Both App and Control tables are populated with some entries. When I try to insert an entry in the ApplicationControl table (taking an id from App and an ID from Control) it says:

```
The Insert statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint 
(between ApplicationControl and Control) The conflict occured in table Control,
column ID.
```

Any ideas why? It can insert the Application ID but It can't insert the Control ID and there aren't any differences between these two relations.

```
USE [PicknickDB]
GO

/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[ApplicationControl]    Script Date: 7/10/2013 3:21:29 PM  ******/ 
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ApplicationControl](
[FK_App_ID] [int] NOT NULL,
[FK_Controls_ID] [int] NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_ApplicationControl] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
[FK_App_ID] ASC,
[FK_Controls_ID] ASC
 )WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF,      ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
 ) ON [PRIMARY]

 GO

 ALTER TABLE [dbo].[ApplicationControl]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT       [FK_MapAppControls_Applications] FOREIGN KEY([FK_App_ID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Application] ([App_ID])
ON UPDATE CASCADE
ON DELETE CASCADE
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[ApplicationControl] CHECK CONSTRAINT   [FK_MapAppControls_Applications]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[ApplicationControl]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_MapAppControls_Controls] FOREIGN KEY([FK_App_ID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Control] ([ID])
ON UPDATE CASCADE
ON DELETE CASCADE
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[ApplicationControl] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_MapAppControls_Controls]
GO
```

Comment: Can you post your actual DDL please? There may e.g. be a bug in the FK , e.g. referencing the wrong table.

Comment: From the design perspective it looks fine and I have 5 similar tables (Many to Many relationship) for which the inserting works fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[ApplicationControl]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT 

[FK_MapAppControls_Controls] FOREIGN KEY([FK_App_ID]) --Really?

REFERENCES [dbo].[Control] ([ID])
ON UPDATE CASCADE
ON DELETE CASCADE
```

So, `FK_App_ID` is used as a reference to both the `Application` **and** the `Control` table?

I'd suggest that that should be `FK_Controls_ID` instead.

Answer (score 0):

In cases like this it is best to turn on Profiler and see exactly what values it is trying to insert. This may lead to seeing why there is a problem. My most likely guess is that the value being sent to the insert for the second table is NULL  because the code forgot to set it somehwere.